# Invalid Typecast

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

When I try to cast `Array of Integer` to `TArray<Integer>` in a procedure I get an error `E2089 Invalid typecast`. How can I type cast it so that it will work?

```
program Project11;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Math;

type
  TArrayManager<T> = record
    class procedure Shuffle(var A: TArray<T>); static;
  end;

class procedure TArrayManager<T>.Shuffle(var A: TArray<T>);
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Temp: T;
begin
  for I := High(A) downto 1 do
  begin
    J := RandomRange(0, I);
    Temp := A[I];
    A[I] := A[J];
    A[J] := Temp;
  end;
end;

procedure Test(var A: Array of Integer);
begin
  TArrayManager<Integer>.Shuffle(TArray<Integer>(A)); // Invalid typecast????
end;

var
  A: Array of Integer;
begin
  // TArrayManager<Integer>.Shuffle(TArray<Integer>(A)); // Works
  Test(A);

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast an open array parameter to a dynamic array. They are simply incompatible. If you wish to operate on a slice of the array, without copying, I'm afraid that you will need to pass the array and the indices separately.  Like this:

```
procedure Foo(var A: TArray<Integer>; Index, Count: Integer);
begin
  // operate on A[Index] to A[Index+Count-1]
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

The type "array of X" means something different as a parameter than as a variable.  Here it's an [open array](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html), which is actually something very different from a dynamic array.

If you want to pass around a dynamic array, you should make the param type `TArray<integer>`.

Comment: Unfortunately I would love to pass it as an open array parameter but I cannot due to the fact that `Slice` function will not allow it.

Comment: @user3764855: Is there anything `Slice` can do that `Copy` can't?

Comment: An actual open array parameter can be a dynamic array, a static array or even an ad-hoc array when you use an open array constructor. So you can't treat it as a dynamic array, because it may not be one.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You cannot inline an method with open array parameter. So this is a big drawback.

Comment: @MasonWheeler `Copy` will copy the complete array. `Slice` will use just part of it. @RudyVelthuis might know more about it.

Comment: @user3764855: I don't quite see the problem. Passing it as an open array parameter would be wrong anyway. Make it TArray<Integer> and all is well.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You can use `TArray<Integer>` with `Slice`? When was that changed.

Comment: @user3764855: `Copy(SomeArray)` will indeed copy the entire array. `Copy(SomeArray, 0, SomeCount)` won't.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Interesting. So it acts exactly as `Slice` for low counts. Why not then just `Move` ?

Comment: @user3764855: No, you can't use Slice. You can use Copy, though.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993428/passing-slice-of-a-static-dynamic-array-by-reference-with-start-and-length-speci/15993429#15993429) says `Copy` will indeed make a full copy of the array. Wouldn't it be possible to reimplement `Slice` for dynamic arrays?

Comment: In this case I would definitely agree with Mason. The array you are seeing is an open array. In memory it looks more like a static array than a dynamic array.

Comment: @user3764855: I just tried it. The link is wrong. `Copy(SomeDynArray, 0, SomeCount);` works as expected. It could be that this was not always possible, in pre-XE days, but in XE6, it works.

Comment: And also in XE. Couldn't try with 2010, as I didn't install it here.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Everything that `Slice` can do, `Copy` cannot. The very raison d'etre for `Slice` is that it does not make a copy.

Comment: @Rudy, I never said that `Copy(SomeDynArray,0,SomeCount);` did not work. On the contrary, it works but has the negative effect that the array is copied, and that was the essence of my question.

Comment: @Rudy It is perverse to suggest that the standard function named `Copy` does not copy. Would you care to retract that erroneous statement?

Comment: @David: Where did I say that?

Comment: Hmmm... I did say that `Copy` will copy the entire array, but `Copy(A, B, C)` won't. Is that the statement you meant? It does copy of course, but **not the entire array**.

Comment: Yes, I see that I misinterpreted what you said. Sorry.